# Ajax Data Returning Undefined Object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The jquery is going to a .php to retrive data, and it is successfully retriving information, but the information is returning as undefined when placed on a page.

```
var userId = $("#userid").val();

$(function()
{
$.ajax({
  url: "../apipages/getprofilecomment.php?userId=${userId}",
  method: "GET",
  type: "json",
  cache: false,
  success: function(comment){
       $('#usercommentdiv').append("<li>" + comment.user_name + ':' + comment.profile_comment + ',' + comment.time_added + "</li>");
  }
});
});
```

This is the .php page that is returning the data:

```
<?php
include ("../db/database.php");
include ("../classes/profilecommentclass.php");
include ("../classes/userclass.php");

session_start();

$userId = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$userClassHandler = new User($db, $userId);
$profileCommentHandler = new ProfileComment($db);
$userNameData = $userClassHandler->getUserName();
$profileComment = $profileCommentHandler->getAllFromComment(34);
$profileCommentArray = array(
"userName" => $_SESSION["user_name"],
"user_profile_comment" => $profileComment["profile_comment"],
"time_added" =>  $profileComment["time_added"],
"time_updated" =>  $profileComment["time_updated"]
);
echo json_encode($profileCommentArray);
?>
```

This is what is being returned at: apipages/getprofilecomment.php?userId=${userId}

```
{"userName":"Acidify","user_profile_comment":"Working to get this app running!!!","time_added":"2019-12-14 00:51:04","time_updated":"15:00:00"}
```

Note: No particular concerned with the user_name being null.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? I think you might be hitting the wrong URL.

Comment: check returned comment using an alert. alert(JSON.stringify(comment));  if all data are there, try adding comment = JSON.parse(comment); before append.

Comment: It is returning the data, but when put in comment.table_name, it does not work. It comes back as undefined. The alert fed back the data.

Answer (score 0):

Change `type: "json"` to `dataType: "json"` in the ajax setup and the parse will occur automatically